# Cocoa Pods Error message after attempting to install a new pod

Tags: rubygems, xcode5, afnetworking, cocoapods

Ive just installed cocoaPods successfully and as I follow the step-by-step guide on adding I new pod a get the following error it the terminal:

> Setting up CocoaPods master repo [!] Unable to locate the executable
>   `git`
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/claide-0.5.0/lib/claide/command.rb:281:in
>   `run': undefined method`verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.31.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in
>   `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.31.1/bin/pod:33
>   from /usr/bin/pod:23:in`load' from /usr/bin/pod:23

This happens after typing in $pod install or just $pod in the Terminal.

I created my pod file by adding a new file of the type "Empty" with the name podfile. The file was saved to the correct project directory.

I've actually what to install AFNetworking on another app but to keep everything simple I created a "sample project".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing Git. You can run `which git` and it will probably return `git not found`. If that is the case you need to install the command line tools with `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Thanks for the help Keith! And just incase someone else has this problem I'm going to post the steps I took.

Comment: Start Xcode on the Mac.
Choose Preferences from the Xcode menu.
In the General panel, click Downloads.
On the Downloads window, choose the Components tab.
Click the Install button next to Command Line Tools